# Best Database to store html-files (or files in general)

Tags: database, sqlite, nosql, storage

What is the best Database-Type (document-oriented,relational,key-value etc.) to store a html file (small sizes, ~max. 700kb) into Database?

Currently I´m using sqlite3 with python, but it seems to get pretty slow if the number of entries/files exceeds 3000 (the .db-file is about 260mb then). Besides that, sqlite is not suited for multiprocessing-usecases.

sqlite schema is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE articles (url TEXT NOT NULL,published DATETIME,title TEXT, fetched TEXT NOT
    NULL,section TEXT,PRIMARY KEY (url), FOREIGN KEY(url) references
    contents(url));
CREATE TABLE contents(url TEXT NOT NULL,date DATETIME,content TEXT,PRIMARY KEY (url));

CREATE TABLE shares (url TEXT NOT NULL, date DATETIME,likes INTEGER NOT NULL,
                    totals INTEGER NOT NULL,clicks INTEGER, comments INTEGER NOT                
                    NULL,share INTEGER NOT NULL, 
                    tweets INTEGER NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(date,url),FOREIGN KEY (url)       
                     REFERENCES articles(url));
```

And the html files go to contents

Comment: How does your sqlite3 schema look like ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you want to store them on the file system?

Comment: I don´t wan´t to, but i thought i have to :) Storing them on the file system was caused by two reasons: a) Writing files is multiprocessing capable (each process cann write) while writing into the sqlite-db is not (you have to gather all the fetched html files in another representation, f.e. a list, and insert them into the db in one single statement/process). This could be a problem when you deal with >1000 html files.. b) maybe I´m wrong, but i don´t know wether sqlite is "made" for storing html-documents (scalability etc.)..is i mentioned, it got pretty soon pretty slow :)

Answer (score 0):

For a document-centric database that uses a URL as the primary key, and which also has to support multiple concurrent writers, you might wish to consider one of the noSQL databases over SQLite. There are currently 122 of them listed [here](http://nosql-database.org/).

What does "pretty slow" mean to you? And are you certain the perceived slowness is @ the database?

Comment: Maybe it was due to  multiprocessed, parallel connections, which caused a lock in the db, but after that the insert of a single html-file took >20 seconds...i tried to recover the db with the backup-function from sqlite, but the backuped db was as slow as the original (an "fresh" and empty , newly created db took about <1 second --> scalability-problem?). That´s why i thought that sqlite isn´t best suited for storing files or large amount of text in it..

Comment: SQLite's file-locking approach is not optimal for multiple concurrent writers. You'd probably do better with MVCC concurrency. Look into CouchDB, for example. Scalability issues normally present themselves in the real-world multi-concurrent-writer scenario, not with a single reader/writer. How large was that single HTML file that took > 20 seconds to insert? Perhaps your writer is waiting on a file-lock to be released, and continually retrying--are other writes going on simultaneously?

Comment: It was about 500kb...it seems that it is waiting for a lock to be released, although no other writes are attemmpted parallel. That´s why i doubted the scalability of sqlite. Maybe i should store all the concurrently downloading html-files/text in a list and then write them all in a central insert into the db ..so you think, sqlite should be scalable enough in general?

Answer (score 0):

`so you think, sqlite should be scalable enough in general?`

There is no "in general" scenario in the actual world. No, I do not think it would scale well for a document-centric application where the records can be 500K. SQLite is not optimized to scale well in a BUSY MULTIPLE CONCURRENT WRITERS SCENARIO, where "busy" is a multivariable function involving the number of writes per second and the size of the record being written and how many indexes are on the table. In brief, the more disk-intensive (*ergo* time-consuming) the write operation, the less well it well scale. In other words, the larger the record and/or the more heavily indexed the table is, the fewer writes-per-second can be accommodated. And a 500K record is a very large record indeed.  You'd be better served with MVCC.

Comment: Okay, so I´ll have a look at CouchDB, switch to MySQL (or continue with sqlite & write the file in the filesystem)